# Abandoned Purchase

Tags: ownership

I sell online. My customers build a box with me to save on shipping. After 30 days of inactivity I close boxes,pack and bill for shipping. I also ship when a customer requests. I've sent repeated messages for the customer to pay their shipping. They ignore us and refuse to pay their shipping. Its been over 30 days. What can I do legally? Can items be returned to stock?

Comment: In what country? Did you sell the contents of the box, or just the box? How did the contents arrive to you?

Comment: Has the customer paid for the contents already?